# Como puedo hacer un array

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Hola como puedo hacer para obtener todos los id de la consulta mysql y convertirlos en un array que quede así

```
"data": [
     [
       "100",
       "Carlos Luna",
       "Credito 30D",
       "14:15:00",
       "2018-05-09"
     ],
     [
       "104",
       "sadfsadf",
       "Contado",
       "12:32:00",
       "2018-06-18"
     ]
   ]
```

y mandarlo por json este es el código:

```
<?php 
            include'configuracion/config.php';

            $q = "SELECT id FROM productos ORDER by id DESC ";
            $consult = mysqli_query($conexion,$q);
            while ($fila= mysqli_fetch_assoc($consult)){

            array($fila['id']);
            echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            exit;

             }

 ?>
```

de esta manera solo consigo que me mande el ultimo id
y esta es la estructura de la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Como lo puedo hacer?**

Comment: Creo que para lograrlo nos hacen falta detalles como la estructura de la tabla ¿Podrías añadirla, por favor?

Comment: Podrías agregar también cómo están llegando los datos al archivo JS, es decir cómo los está retornando PHP o en otras palabras, de qué quieres pasar al ejemplo que pones. Otra observación es que veo que haces un `json_encode($data)` pero no la asignación de la variable previo a hacer la codificación.

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo tu código, da la sensación de que intentas conseguir algo así:

```
<?php 
include'configuracion/config.php';
$q = "SELECT id FROM productos ORDER by id DESC ";
$consult = mysqli_query($conexion,$q);
if($fila = mysqli_fetch_all($consult))
    echo json_encode($fila,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

O, si no te interesan los nombres de los campos, como indicas en tu array de muestra, así:

```
<?php 
include'configuracion/config.php';
$q = "SELECT id FROM productos ORDER by id DESC ";
$consult = mysqli_query($conexion,$q);
$todo=[];
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($consult))
    $todo[]=$fila;
echo json_encode($todo,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```